# WPF Extending Window

Tags: wpf, inheritance, window

So I have a bunch of WPF Windows in my Windows Application.
I want each window to have a context menu that has one item ( see the code bellow ). However, I don't feel like copying and pasting this code everywhere. I would like to somehow extend the WPF Window class ( and call it PrintableWindow ) and somehow make every window be an extension of the PrintableWindow ....Is this possible ???

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.Items>
            <MenuItem Header="Print"
                      Click="mnuPrint_Click">
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to extend window to do accomplish this, just created a global style for all windows.

In your app.xaml file:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Items>
                    <MenuItem Header="Print" Command="Print" />
                </ContextMenu.Items>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You will have to create a handler for the print command in the window if you want to print from a particular window.  Even better, if you are using a view model you can just bind to your command.

Comment: I just want to add, that you need to set up x:Key attribute for Window style and to assign Style explicitly for each Window. It's a known issue that Window doesn't select style automatically from application resources by TargetType.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `Window` class called `PrintableWindow` which derives from 
`Window` and then modify any other `Window` instances to derive from your `PrintableWindow` versus `Window`. This way all `Window` instances will be of type `PrintableWindow` which has your `ContextMenu` and handler associated with it.

Comment: this seems almost impossible !

Comment: well not "impossible" but it's seems to be very difficult to extend the Window class .

Comment: Backfilling code which is already complete will take a refactoring effort but once you are "caught" up I'm not sure where the difficulty surfaces?